# How to marshal struct to XML with alphabetically-sorted elements?

Tags: go

I need to get XML string with ordered elements from structs with unordered fields.

There is main struct:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
    OtherData interface{}
}
```

And there are also a great many other structs, such as:

```
type SomeStruct1 struct {
    Job   string
    Hobby string
}

type SomeStruct2 struct {
    SkillName  string
    SkillValue int
    *SomeStruct3
}
```

These structs can have other embedded structs.

I get structs like this:

```
    sample := &Person{}
    sample.Name = "Vasya"
    sample.Age = 35
    sample.OtherData = SomeStruct1{"programmer", "driving"}
```

Then I need to get XML with elements ordered by their names:

```
<Person>
    <Age>35</Age>
    <Name>Vasya</Name>
    <OtherData>
        <Hobby>driving</Hobby>
        <Job>programmer</Job>
    </OtherData>
</Person>
```

Comment: XML tags appear in the order of the respective fields in the struct types, so change the order of the fields.

Comment: There is a rather easy way to do it with JSON but unfortunately not XML...